# Retry HTTP request (Java 11 - HttpClient)

Tags: java, http, request, retry-logic, java-http-client

### Problem

Using `HttpClient` from Java 11 (JDK, not Apache), how can I retry requests?

Lets say I want to retry a request up to **10 times** if it did not return a **status code** of `200` or threw an exception.

---

### Attempt

Currently I am composing the returned future with re-schedules in a loop and I am wondering whether there might be a better or more elegant way.

```
CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<Foo>> task = client.sendAsync(request, bodyHandler);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    task = task.thenComposeAsync(response -> response.statusCode() == 200 ?
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response) :
        client.sendAsync(request, bodyHandler));
}

// Do something with 'task' ...
```

And if we add retries for exceptional cases as well, I end up with

```
CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<Foo>> task = client.sendAsync(request, bodyHandler);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    task = task.thenComposeAsync(response ->
            response.statusCode() == 200 ?
            CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response) :
            client.sendAsync(request, bodyHandler))
        .exceptionallyComposeAsync(e ->
            client.sendAsync(request, bodyHandler));
}

// Do something with 'task' ...
```

Unfortunately there does not seem to be any `composeAsync` that triggers for both, regular completion and exceptional. There is `handleAsync` but it does not `compose`, the lambda is required to return `U` and not `CompletionStage<U>` there.

---

### Other frameworks

For the sake of QA, I am also interested in answers that show how to achieve this with other frameworks, but I wont accept them.

For example, I have seen a library called *Failsafe* which might offer an elegant solution to this (see [jodah.net/failsafe](https://jodah.net/failsafe/)).

---

### Reference

For reference, here are some related JavaDoc links:

- [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)
- [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)
- [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to do something along these lines instead (assuming no security manager):

```
public static int MAX_RESEND = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpResponse.BodyHandler<String> handler = HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://example.com/")).build();
    var response = client.sendAsync(request, handler)
            .thenComposeAsync(r -> tryResend(client, request, handler, 1, r));
    // do something with response...
}

public static <T> CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<T>>
        tryResend(HttpClient client, HttpRequest request, BodyHandler<T> handler,
                 int count, HttpResponse<T> resp) {
    if (resp.statusCode() == 200 || count >= MAX_RESEND) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(resp);
    } else {
        return client.sendAsync(request, handler)
                .thenComposeAsync(r -> tryResend(client, request, handler, count+1, r));
    }
}
```

And if you wanted to handle both the regular and exceptional case you could do something like:

```
public static int MAX_RESEND = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    BodyHandler<String> handler = BodyHandlers.ofString();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://example.com/")).build();
    CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> response = 
        client.sendAsync(request, handler)
            .handleAsync((r, t) -> tryResend(client, request, handler, 1, r, t))
            .thenCompose(Function.identity());
    // do something with response ...
}

public static boolean shouldRetry(HttpResponse<?> r, Throwable t, int count) {
    if (r != null && r.statusCode() == 200 || count >= MAX_RESEND) return false;
    if (t instanceof ... ) return false;
    return true;
}

public static <T> CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<T>>
        tryResend(HttpClient client, HttpRequest request,
                  BodyHandler<T> handler, int count,
                  HttpResponse<T> resp, Throwable t) {
    if (shouldRetry(resp, t, count)) {
        return client.sendAsync(request, handler)
                .handleAsync((r, x) -> tryResend(client, request, handler, count + 1, r, x))
                .thenCompose(Function.identity());
    } else if (t != null) {
        return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(t);
    } else {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Too me this looks like the same but using recursion instead of a loop to produce the same composition of futures, no?

Comment: Sorry I misread the original proposed code - at a second glance I believe it would work. The difference is that with my suggestion you won't stack up all these dependent actions in advance. For the sake of the argument, change 10 into 10000 and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: And BTW, it's not recursive - since it's all async: it's simply scheduling a resend. Unrelated note: if you wanted to handle both exceptional & status in the same method you could also use `CF::handle`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use import
org.eclipse.microprofile.faulttolerance.Retry;

if you use microprofiler or search for equivalent

@Retry